# Android display a duplicated/replicated layout?

Tags: android, layout, replication

First of all, I would like to clarify that I am not very experienced  with Android, but, is there a way to duplicate/replicate the displayed layout on an android phone? For example, I'm at the home screen, and my phone shows 2 of the same images right next to each other on my screen.

Here is a picture of an example of what I am talking about. (You can disregard the watermark/frame thing):

http://i1135.photobucket.com/albums/m637/mxmark825/Diagram.jpg

Basically what I want to try to do is make the phone show 2 layouts like it would if it had 2 separate screens on the front of the phone.

Any ideas/help are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can define layout in separate xml like dup.xml and then make you activity layout xml like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/dup" />
    <include layout="@layout/dup" />
</LinearLayout>
```